# Intellisense in VS code for java is only working if I enable and disable extensions when I create a new file

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, intellisense

If I create a new file Intellisense stops working.
On creation of a new file basic things work but the full list of suggestions doesn't show up.

I either have to reopen vs code , even then it doesn't work sometimes. It only works when I disable and reinstall the Extension Pack for java in Microsoft.

Comment: There are similar issues: https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/3191

Comment: out of curiosity, does the `Restart Java Language Server` also work as a workaround?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/3191#issuecomment-1635181642

> this issue has been fixed in the latest vscode@1.80.1 version.